# Why does the circuit tranconductance remain unchanged after cascode?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier

I have a simple cascode amplifier as follows:

[image]

The circuit transconductance remains the same as if the cascode was not there. i.e.
$$G_M=g_{m1}$$

Why is it so?

I initially think the circuite transconductance would be the product of the component transconductances, like
$$G_M=g_{m1}\cdot g_{m2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transistor M2 is acting as a current buffer with a gain of 1.  A cascode is not a cascade.  It is used to increase isolation and stability, not increase gain.  Make two of these and put them in series if you need more gain.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the answer. But I still don't get it why the transconductance does not change.

Comment: Well, the transconductance does change, but not by very much.  M1 gives you the gain.  What does M2 do?  Vb holds the gate at one voltage, and the transistor has to keep a big enough Vgs to stay in saturation.  Since Vgs on M2 doesn't change much, the transistor does not really affect the gain.  However, since it holds the voltage on the drain of M1 constant, the miller effect on M1 is greatly reduced and the amplifier becomes more stable.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that the gain after cascode is roughly the same. But it till does not answer the question why the transconductance does not change...

Comment: Transconductance is the ratio of the voltage in to the current out.  M2 is a current buffer (current in = current out).  Hence the effect on the transconductance is negligible.  Basically, M1 sets the current at the output and M2 sets the voltage.

Comment: Can I ask where this diagram came from? Did you make it with XCircuit or are there class notes posted somewhere?